# On a item detail page, how to show certain items from another list?

Tags: related-list

This instance of SharePoint is SharePoint 2013 Server. I work with SharePoint Designer 2013.

In this scenario, I have two lists: Cases and Notes. I want to link each Note to a Case. There can be many notes per case, but only one case per note.

I have a Display Item page, and below the details of the Case I want to include a web part that shows the Notes that are linked to this Case. There is a "lookup" column in the Notes list that connects the two.

I can't figure out the right way to use filter, etc. to make what I want happen.

Comment: Have a look at this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYU8bQ6Sw8I

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is not to use Designer, but to use InfoPath to edit the display item page. You can Google 'InfoPath (whatever year this is for) lookup field', but here's an [example](https://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/create-infopath-form-with-lookup-functionality-to-sharepoint-list/) of the steps in detail. It's not a one click solution, but here's the high level:

1. Add a data connection
2. Filter the data connection based on a value on the display form (such as a case ID or a record ID)
3. Display the fields you want either in a table or as a repeating table item.